# Is my working or 'logic' correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Question is if I am able to create a DNF from ¬(¬pɅ(pVq)) to exactly like this : (¬pɅq) V (¬pɅ¬q) ?

I have tried for a long time and here is what I worked out which I'm not able to find out if I am right or wrong to work it out this way..

Proposition: ¬(¬pɅ(pVq))

= ¬p   Absorption Law

¬p Ʌ T   Identity Law

T = (q V ¬q)  <-- this is my assumption. Need verification on this if I can assume it this way thanks!

Therefore,
¬p Ʌ (q V ¬q)

Finally I use the distributive law on the above statement, assuming that i can take  ¬q = r.

= (¬pɅq) V (¬pɅ¬q)

Hence I can create the requested DNF from ¬(¬pɅ(pVq))

Comment: YES : it is correct that $T = (q \lor ¬q)$.

Comment: But what about your first step : Absorption Law ?

Answer (score 0):

1) $¬[¬p \land (p \lor q)]$

2) $[p \lor \lnot (p \lor q)]$ --- by De Morgan

3) $[p \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)]$ --- by De Morgan again

4) $[(p \lor \lnot p) \land (p \lor \lnot q)]$ --- by Distributivity

5) $(p \lor \lnot q)$ --- because $p \lor \lnot p \equiv T$ and $T \land a \equiv a$

---

1) $(¬p \land q) \lor (¬p \land ¬q)$

2) $[¬p \land (q \lor ¬q)]$ --- by Distributivity

3) $\lnot p$

---

*Conclusion* : the two formulae are **not** equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the help! but what if the statement is  

¬(pɅ(pVq)) 

instead? I am able to prove from this statement that the 2 formulae are equivalent by following my initial steps